# Define an element in XSD which is an ENUM and has one attribute

Tags: java, xml, enums, xsd

I'd like to have the XSD for the following xml:

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <child1>value1_1</child1>
        <child2 att="att1">value2_1</child2>
    </tag>
</root>
```

With the following XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root" type="rootMeta"/>
    <xs:element name="tag" type="tagMeta"/>

    <xs:complexType name="rootMeta">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tag" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="tagMeta">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child1" type="enum1"/>
            <xs:element name="child2" type="enum2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>`

    <xs:simpleType name="enum1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="value1_1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="value1_2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- And here the problem comes -->

    <xs:complexType name="enum2">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="value2_1"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="value2_2"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:attribute name="att" type="attMeta" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="attMeta">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="att1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="att2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The definition is wrong and the validation cannot be done, can anyone explain me how shall I define *enum2* to have an enum as a value and also an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve want you may be to define a simpleType that you can extend afterwards to add an attribute:

```
<xs:complexType name="enum2">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="enum2_text_values">
            <xs:attribute name="att" type="attMeta" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

It relies upon the *enum2_text_values* simpleType that has been mentioned, that you can define like follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="enum2_text_values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="value2_1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="value2_2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```